# How do i pass data from Thread to UI-Thread and view that data?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

I really don't know how to properly get data from a Thread.

In a thread (or Task, doesnt matter) i want to calculate a lot of doubles. When this is finished i want to show this data in a grid and in a graphic-chart. So i tried to return some type of

```
 Observable<List<double>>
```

When i then wanted to create a "new ViewModel(data)", i get exceptions cause of threads.

So how do i properly get such a list back from a thread and use it in UI?
Or maybe pass this data while calculating to show some live values would also be nice..

thanks for answers, just need a few tips

Comment: You would usually use the Dispatcher of the UI thread. Start reading the Remarks section on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx). There is also an MSDN article about the [Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of functionality is common and is often accomplished using the [`BackgroundWorker` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). There is a code example on the linked page and you can find another with feedback in my answer to the [How to correctly implement a BackgroundWorker with ProgressBar updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334583/how-to-correctly-implement-a-backgroundworker-with-progressbar-updates/19334879#19334879) question on this website.

Alternatively, you can use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) object from the UI thread to pass values to that thread. Note that each thread has it's own `Dispatcher`, so be sure to call the one from the UI thread. You can use this little helper method:

```
public object RunOnUiThread(Delegate method)
{
    return Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate
{
    // You can run any number of lines of code on the UI Thread here
});
```

Or inline, like this:

```
RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate { UpdateData(); });
```

I have this method in a separate class that has constructors like this:

```
private UiThreadManager(Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    Dispatcher = dispatcher;
}

public UiThreadManager() : this(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher) { }
```

I call this constructor on the UI thread to ensure that the `Dispatcher` that I will be using is in fact the `Dispatcher` from the UI thread.