# wpf progress bar animation not visible

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I have problem with my app. I want to add simple progress bar, in designer looks normal, but when I start app, progress bar is empty inside
my code is simple:

`<ProgressBar Name="pbarStatus" Height="55" Value="50" IsIndeterminate="True"/>`

When I just setIsIndeterminate=False then there is only green border with white field inside

I cant send pic (no 10 reputation)...

In new project it works fine, so problem is only with my. Can someone help me where I can find problem?

**EDIT**

my behaviour IsIndeterminate=True [Link](http://picpaste.com/Przechwytywanie-blJ0o684.PNG)

my behaviour IsIndeterminate=False [Link](http://picpaste.com/Przechwytywanie1-S13h93Wf.PNG)

**EDIT 2**

Thanks, but minimum and maximum I left default (0 and 100) in visual studio in designer progress bar looks as it should (also even when I change value in designer mode), but when I press F5 button (debug) and I start app, progress bar looks as on pictures (is empty or just green border instead animation). It looks like I'm lost animation somehow...

Regards 
Andrzej

Comment: Well you can upload your pic here for example: http://picpaste.com/
But you can also post your code becouse there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour:
IsIndeterminate = true: 
http://imgur.com/4OenXrk or http://picpaste.com/progress_indeterminate.gif

IsIndeterminate = false with Value set to 50: http://imgur.com/dYWaxuC or
http://picpaste.com/progress_not_indeterminate.PNG

Comment: Andrzej, as I look at the picture with IsIndeterminate=False, the behaviour is correct - you've set the progress to 50%. The value of the progress bar must be within Minimum and Maximum. Minimum is 0 default, Maximum is 100 (inherited from RangeBase but overridden and set to 100).
In your app you should change the Value property to see the effect.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to the [How to correctly implement a BackgroundWorker with ProgressBar updates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334583/how-to-correctly-implement-a-backgroundworker-with-progressbar-updates/19334879#19334879) question.

Comment: @Mike did you see those pics from andrzej? If u want to see the behaviour of <ProgressBar Name="pbarStatus" Height="55" Value="50" IsIndeterminate="True"/> or false without any custom styles take a look at links in my prev. comment

Comment: @eren, yes, I've seen your pictures. Basically, for IsIndeterminate="True" you need an animation to show the behaviour.

Comment: @Andrzej, one more thing - is this progress bar already a part of a bigger application? Isn't the style overridden somewhere?