# WPF C# Progress Bar different Window

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I´m trying to figure out how to implement a progress bar in my application.

I´ve read some articles like this [How to correctly implement a BackgroundWorker with ProgressBar updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334583/how-to-correctly-implement-a-backgroundworker-with-progressbar-updates), and I caught how it works. My doubt is how will I call and update the progressbar.xaml since I´m executing the sql in the PendenciaController.cs.

PendenciaConsulta.xaml.cs

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Progress<long> progress = null;

progress = new Progress<long>((i) =>
{
    try
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { PBar.Value = i; });
    }

    catch { }
});

pendenciaController = new PendenciaController(progress);
pendenciaController.PendenciaConsultar((bool)chkFollowUp.IsChecked); //The error occurs here

pendenciaController.PopularListas();

StatusController statusController = new StatusController();
ObservableCollection<Status> ListaStatus = null;
dataContext = new DataContext();
this.listaPendencia = this.pendenciaController.ListaPendencia;
ListaStatus = statusController.StatusConsultar();
this.DataContext = dataContext;
dtgPendencia.ItemsSource = this.listaPendencia;
lblQuantidadeRegistros.Content = "Quantidade de registros: " + this.listaPendencia.Count;

PopularCombos();
});
```

PendenciaController.cs

```
private Progress<long> _progress;

public PendenciaController(Progress<long> progress)
{
    _progress = progress;
}

public void PendenciaConsultar(bool followUp)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = null;

#region Select e conversão do DataSet
try
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexao());
    conn.Open();

    //Select da tabela tblPendencia
    StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder();

    cmd.Append("SELECT P.pendenciaId, " +
                     " P.contrato, " +
                     " P.adAm, " +
                     " P.diasDecorridos, " +
                     " P.corretora, " +
                     " P.produto, " +
                     " P.clienteNome, " +
                     " P.clienteCnpj, " +
                     " P.aberturaData, " +
                     " P.pendenciaTipo, " +
                     " P.lastro, " +
                     " P.garantiaDescricao, " +
                     " P.observacao, " +
                     " P.vencimentoData, " +
                     " P.liquidacaoData, " +
                     " P.rating, " +
                     " P.operacaoValor, " +
                     " P.pendenciaNivel, " +
                     " P.pendenciaValorFator, " +
                     " P.porContrato, " +
                     " P.officer, " +
                     " P.centroCusto, " +
                     " P.isCritico, " +
                     " P.statusId, " +
                     " P.clienteGrupo, " +
                     " P.followUp, " +
                     " P.carenciaInicio, " +
                     " P.carenciaFim, " +
                     " P.moeda, " +
                     " P.documentoTipo, " +
                     " P.tipo, " +
                     " (SELECT S.statusDescricao " +
                        " FROM tblStatus S " +
                       " WHERE S.statusId = P.statusId) as statusDescricao" +
                        " FROM tblPendencia P");

    if (!followUp)
    {
        cmd.Append(" WHERE ((P.followUp <= NOW()) " +
                      " OR (P.followUp IS NULL))");
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Append(" WHERE ((P.followUp <= NOW()) " +
                      " OR (P.followUp >= NOW()) " +
                      " OR (P.followUp IS NULL))");
    }


    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd.ToString(), conn);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "tblPendencia");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables["tblPendencia"];

    Pendencia pendencia = null;

    this.ListaPendencia = new List<Pendencia>();

    if (ds.Tables != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //foreach (DataRow dtRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dtRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];

            pendencia = new Pendencia();

            pendencia.AberturaData = dtRow["aberturaData"].ToString();
            pendencia.AdAm = dtRow["adAm"].ToString();
            pendencia.CentroCusto = dtRow["centroCusto"].ToString();
            pendencia.ClienteCnpj = dtRow["clienteCnpj"].ToString();
            pendencia.ClienteNome = dtRow["clienteNome"].ToString();
            pendencia.Contrato = dtRow["contrato"].ToString();
            pendencia.Corretora = dtRow["corretora"].ToString();
            pendencia.DiasDecorridos = dtRow["diasDecorridos"].ToString();
            pendencia.GarantiaDescricao = dtRow["garantiaDescricao"].ToString();
            pendencia.Lastro = dtRow["lastro"].ToString();
            pendencia.LiquidacaoData = dtRow["liquidacaoData"].ToString();
            pendencia.Observacao = dtRow["observacao"].ToString();
            pendencia.Officer = dtRow["officer"].ToString();
            pendencia.OperacaoValor = dtRow["operacaoValor"].ToString();
            pendencia.PendenciaId = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow["pendenciaId"]);
            pendencia.PendenciaNivel = dtRow["pendenciaNivel"].ToString();
            pendencia.PendenciaValorFator = dtRow["pendenciaValorFator"].ToString();
            pendencia.StatusId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtRow["statusId"].ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dtRow["statusId"]);
            pendencia.Produto = dtRow["produto"].ToString();
            pendencia.Rating = dtRow["rating"].ToString();
            pendencia.PendenciaTipo = dtRow["pendenciaTipo"].ToString();
            pendencia.VencimentoData = dtRow["vencimentoData"].ToString();
            pendencia.ClienteGrupo = dtRow["clienteGrupo"].ToString();
            pendencia.FollowUp = dtRow["followUp"].ToString();
            pendencia.CarenciaInicioData = dtRow["carenciaInicio"].ToString();
            pendencia.CarenciaFimData = dtRow["carenciaFim"].ToString();
            pendencia.DocumentoTipo = dtRow["documentoTipo"].ToString();
            pendencia.StatusDescricao = dtRow["statusDescricao"].ToString();
            pendencia.PorContratoDescricao = dtRow["porContrato"].ToString();
            pendencia.Moeda = dtRow["moeda"].ToString();
            pendencia.Tipo = dtRow["tipo"].ToString();

            pendencia.IsCritico = Convert.ToBoolean(dtRow["isCritico"]);
            pendencia.StatusId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtRow["statusId"].ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dtRow["statusId"]);

            this.ListaPendencia.Add(pendencia);

            ((IProgress<long>)(_progress)).Report((long)i);

        }
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

finally { conn.Close(); }
#endregion
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Come on! If you downvote say at least why!

Comment: Himmm. Many problems. First implement a background worker to do job. Then, separate view and worker logic and finally bind the progress value

Comment: I think that the question is clear enough. Sometimes people is too nitpicking.

Comment: I disagree, as there's no implementation within the provided code that shows any attempt on @Denis part to use any `BackgroundWorker` nor any reference to any `ProgressBar` that I see, despite him saying that  he _"caught how it works."_  The code provided has no relevance on the issue/question.

Comment: @gravity as we see, this is subjective, since Ignacio has a different point of view than yours. His answer is more usefull than just downvote my question, as well as he gave me an idea of how to implement the progressbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Progress<T> Class` and `Task`.

Example :

```
public partial class Window25 : Window
{
    public Window25()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Progress<long> progress = null;
            progress = new Progress<long>((i) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Update ProgressBar 
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { PBar.Value = i; });
                }
                    // handle pre-mature closing of window (task cancellation)
                catch { }
            });

            Controller c = new Controller(progress);
            c.Do();
        }
        );
    }
}

public class Controller
{
    Progress<long> _progress;
    public Controller(Progress<long> progress)
    {
        _progress = progress;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        for (long s = 0; s < 99999; ++s)
            ((IProgress<long>)(_progress)).Report((long)s);
    }
}
```

[Progress class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

See if this solves your problem.

Comment: I edited the question as you suggested, but I´m getting the error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." when executing the following command: "pendenciaController.PendenciaConsultar((bool)chkFollowUp.IsChecked);".

I tried to find out what would be the other thread but couldn´t.

Comment: @Denis Get the bool value as `bool checkedStatus = Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { return (bool)chkFollowUp.IsChecked; });` and pass it like `pendenciaController.PendenciaConsultar(checkedStatus )`

Comment: Thanks @AnjumSKhan it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should raise progress events from `PendenciaController` and handle them into `PendenciaConsulta` to update the ProgressBar.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. I wish I could accept 2 answers to mark yours and Anjum's answer as correct but I can´t, so I accepted his cause is more complete. Anyway I upvoted your answer since it helped me as well.

Comment: That's great. No worries.